# Proper use of number of

Tags: numbers

Is it right to say "The service is secured under numbers of protocols"
or it is better to say "The service is secured under number of protocols"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service is secured with a number of protocols.

Or...

The service is secured with several protocols.